# How do I use an animated .gif in my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, graphics

I have an animated gif file that I want to use in my iPhone application, but the animation doesn't work. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you have a serie of images you want to animate you can easily do it with UIImageView:

```
UIImage *blur5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur5.png"];
UIImage *blur6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur6.png"];

self.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:blur5, blur6, nil];
self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 5;
[self.imageView startAnimating];
```

I found this easier than trying to use UIWebView.

Comment: This is correct solution to show animation of images. But this is not the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 7):

UIWebView does not properly display all GIF content. You need to use a UIImageView, but the iPhone OS does not support animated GIFS and only displays the first frame.

So you need to extract all of the other frames first.

Crude example code here:
http://pliep.nl/blog/2009/04/iphone_developer_decoding_an_animated_gif_image_in_objc

Answer (score 5):

You can use source at http://blog.stijnspijker.nl/2009/07/animated-and-transparent-gifs-for-iphone-made-easy/
It has a GIF decoder that you can use directly to get solution.
I successfully used it. But it have some problems with transparency.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by this piece of code:

```
NSArray * imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], nil]; //this will be the frames of animation images in sequence.
 ringImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,200,600,600)];
 ringImage.animationImages = imageArray;
 ringImage.animationDuration = 1.5;//this the animating speed which you can modify
 ringImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
 [ringImage startAnimating];//this method actually does the work of animating your frames.
```

I know its an old thread..but may be helpful for someone..:)

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to decode the gif in your application, and then "frame serve" it to a OpenGL object. This way is less likely to run out of memory for large gifs.