# iphone local animated gif inside main bundle

Tags: iphone, animation, uiwebview, gif

i want to display an animated GIF i've made inside iphone main bundle in UIWebview i've tried

```
NSString *ImageFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.gif"];
// NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body \"style=\"background:url(%@) no-repeat;\">gege</body></html>",ImageFromApp];
```

but it gets me nothing at all 
any idea here wil be very appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone does not support animated GIFs (outsde of the web browser).

Although, it is easy to take a bunch of images, and have the framework animate them.

It is detailed [here in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661108/how-to-use-an-animated-gif-file-in-iphone-application).

Comment: Broken link! Yours works, but that guy's example isnt... someone has to rewrite it again (Referring to the 6+ votes answer's link, just follow it and you'll see)