# Download animated gif from url into UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Okay, so I met this challenge.
I've found several ways to animate still images, by putting them together. The real challenge is when the gif needs to be downloaded from the web. Sooooo.

I know this is a broad question, and needs a lot of code, but I really need your help on this!

How do I download an animated gif, and show it properly?

I really appriciate any help I can get on this!

Andreas :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use an animated gif file in iphone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661108/how-to-use-an-animated-gif-file-in-iphone-application)

Comment: Try this [link](https://github.com/atnan/UIImageView-NDVAnimatedGIFSupport) for Animated GIF support in UIImageView