# Do pretty UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I saw once a library that can do nice `UIActivityIndicatorView` easily but I can not find it. Someone knows or knows another way to make nice `UIActivityIndicatorView` ? something like that
[image: http://hpics.li/64d7b07]

Comment: What do you mean 'nice' ? Can you please be specific.  ?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

I think the activity indicator with the details label is what you're exactly looking for.

Answer (score 16):

I just did something similar today. I'm going to make it a proper subclass, but for now, this should get you started. Adding a UILabel should be easy for you. I'm doing this with ARC so if you need to do memory management please be careful.

```
UIView *activityContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
activityContainer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.25];
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - 40, (self.view.frame.size.height/2) - 40, 80, 80)];
indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
indicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[indicator layer].cornerRadius = 8.0;
[indicator layer].masksToBounds = YES;
[activityContainer addSubview:indicator];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a library like this, but it shouldn't be too hard to create your own (as an embeddable UIView) and animate it.

Maybe even an animated gif? ([related question linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661108/how-to-use-an-animated-gif-file-in-iphone-application))

Answer (score 1):

I created a custom UIView ([Loader Animation](https://github.com/crizzwald/LoaderAnimation)) to which you could load into a subclass of `UIActivity`.